# python script working on Pycharm and cmd but not running when double clicking it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pynput

I made a keylogger using pynput and it runs perfectly and as expected on pycharm and when I open it in python IDE then run it from there and when I navigate to the script folder using cmd and run it from there also using cmd like so:

`python keylogger.py`

But when I double click it the console opens and closes which means the program has errors, But it doesn't!. So I spammed the program and I could get the error that the flashing console screen is displaying:
basically it's in line one

```
from pynput.keyboard import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pynput'
```

yes I installed pynput with pip, yes I have python installed on my system, yes I'm sure that's the error.
I'm windows 10 BTW

what should I do???

Comment: If it runs from a fresh cmd, it should run the same as when clicked (although the terminal wouldn't stay open if the script exits immediately). This assumes that you don't have multiple versions of Python installed

Comment: Not sure but double clicked never did much for me. Have you tried compiling it?

Comment: @cricket_007 I know... that confuses me... and no I don't have multiple versions of python installed... any other ideas?

Comment: @TheFool Yes, as I mentioned it runs perfectly on Pycharm

Comment: @cricket_007 Idk maybe I can share some screenshots to prove?

Comment: The only other problem would be that Pycharm is using a virtualenv to run your code. But that doesn't answer why cmd would work

Comment: @FadiSoltan compiling has nothing to do with pycharm though.

Comment: @TheFool excuse my bad English.

Comment: @cricket_007 exactly!... any more ideas?... shall I send you something? screenshot, error codes... etc

Comment: How about you add `import sys; print(sys.path)`, then run it in each of the different locations and see if anything changes?

Comment: @cricket_007 on Pycharm and the Python IDE it prints out some file paths. but still, nothing changed. clicking on the file not working and with the same error I mentioned above

Comment: But if you print the path before the other import, then you might be able to see some differences

Comment: @cricket_007 indeed... now those random paths are being printed then the same non-logical error comes up to my face again!.

Comment: is it some sort of a glitch??